# Find and rename a file in bash or python

Tags: python, bash, rename

I am trying to run a script in bash or python that locate an nfo file inside a dir and rename it.

Like the dir is in /home/disk/xxx/P and inside there are files and this file named b.nfo that I want to rename to 1.nfo

I tried Both bash and python with no luck

Bash

```
cd /home/disk/xxx/P             
for f in *;do                                        
rename ".nfo" "1.nfo"
done
```

Python

```
dir = '/home/disk/xxx/P'
x = os.listdir(dir)
for f in x:
 if f.endswith('.nfo'):
new = '/home/disk/xxx/P' +'/'+'1.nfo'      
os.system('mv str(f) new')
```

None of these work..  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there only a single file you are trying to rename? just b.nfo?

Comment: What happened when you ran those scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modules `os` and `glob`:

```
import glob
import os

dir_ = '/home/disk/xxx/P'
for fn in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_, '*.nfo')): 
    os.rename(fn, os.path.join(os.path.split(fn)[0], '1.nfo'))
```

Comment: Actually this rename the Old file to oldfile1.nfo

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood  the question. Fixed.

Comment: Just tried again. Works for me.  Isn't there a file  `/home/disk/xxx/P1.nfo`?

Comment: No it created  a file like oldfile1

Comment: I modified my answer. Did you try the new version?

Comment: Are you sure you have `*.nfo` file there in the first place?

Comment: Its not called *.nfo,  it gets extracted from a zip file and can be named whatever and im trying to rename it to 1.nfo

Comment: `*.nfo` is just the pattern for the file, meaning its extension is `.nfo` no matter wat the full file name is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:`os.rename(path_to_file, path_to_renamed_file)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
for fname in glob.glob("/home/disk/*/P/*.nfo"):
    print "Found :",fname
    # now rename it or whatever ...
    new_name = fname.replace(".nfo",".1.nfo")
    os.rename(fname,new_name)
```

the same files would match in bash with `ls /home/disk/*/P/*.nfo`

Comment: This also add a .1 to Old file ..  Maybe i explained bad..  I want to rename the whole name to 1.nfo..

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file in python you can use `os.rename(src, dest)` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm

As for your own code, it didn't work because `os.system('mv str(f) new')` actually executed the command "mv str(f) new". if you want to use params you should have done: `os.system('mv %s %s' % (f, new))`. But anyway don't use os.system, use os.rename(). Its much cleaner and will work on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a single file as it appears you are doing...try:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/disk/xxx/P
findIt=$(find . -type f -name b.nfo)
if [[ ${findIt} != "" ]] ; then
  mv ${findIt} 1.nfo
else
  echo "File was not found"
fi
```

Comment: or `findIt=$(find . -type f "*.nfo")` if you do not know what the file will be called exactly

Comment: you will want to add in better string handling for my comment above if there is a possibility of more than one ".nfo" file being in that location

Comment: find: paths must precede expression: *.nfo
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
File was not found

Comment: @AndrewStef There you go, I wrote the find command incorrectly. Should work now

Comment: Almost there.. Now it says target 1.nfo is not  a directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do. In increasing levels of complexity:

`mv /home/disk/xxx/P/b.nfo /home/disk/xxx/P/1.nfo`

or

```
if [ -f /home/disk/xxx/P/b.nfo   ]; then
   mv /home/disk/xxx/P/b.nfo /home/disk/xxx/P/1.nfo
else
   echo "b.nfo not found"
fi
```

or

```
for nfofile in /home/disk/xxx/P/*.nfo
do
    newname=$(echo $nfofile | <some sort of name transformation>)
    mv $nfofile $newname
done
```